# Unable To Connect using Server Explorer

Tags: c#, connection, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012-express, server-explorer

I'm in Visual Studio 2013, using SQL Server Express 2012, on Windows 7 OS.

With C# code, I CAN connect to the database and query.  For example:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("server=MYSERVER\\SQLEXPRESS; Trusted_Connection=yes; database=MyDatabase; connection timeout=30"))
{

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM tblData";
                cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
                sqlConnection.Open();
                int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                Console.WriteLine(count);  // I get the correct answer.
        }
}
```

That works.  My problem is that if I use Server Explorer within Visual Studio, I cannot connect to the database via that route.  In the Add Connection, MyServer does appear in the server dropdown, but the database dropdown is empty.  When I click Test Connection or OK (leaving Database empty or entering MyDatabase), I get the error: Server was not found or was not accessible.

So I can connect via C# code, but not with Server Explorer.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: try to run VS with Administrator..

Comment: Thanks.  But my problem was that I should have typed in MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS (raja) instead of using the dropdown choice of just MYSERVER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a named instance (**SQLExpress**) of the SQL Server. In the connections window, try typing in the server name as:

**`MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS`**

Comment: I found this post because I was having the same issue. This worked for me. I confirmed the name of my server by opening (START MENU > Microsoft SQL Server 2008 > Configuration Tools > SQL Configuration Server Configuration Manager), then clicking on "SQL Server Services" in the menu that appears, and finding my instance name in the list. The I typed <computer_name>\<sql_instance> into the dropdown.